# How to pass url as parameter from view to controller using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem when using a function with parameter in codeigniter. I want to write a function which when we click the URL in view, automatically uses that URL address as parameter to connect to the function that I made in the controller.

I already use

```
 this->load->helper('url','form','array');
```

View

```
 <?php 
 foreach ($dataView as $items){
    echo "<a href='".site_url("testcontroller/click/".$items['serviceURL']."")."'>".$items>['serviceURL']."</a>".'<br>';    
 ?>
```

Controller

```
 <?php

 public function click($url=null){

      var_dump($url);
      $datauri['url']=$url;
 }
 ?>
```

When I use a dummy variable I see that the URL that already passed is just

```
  < string(5) "http:">
```

but it should be a complete URL such as

> ```
> <http://sos.maracoos.org/stable/sos/hrecos/stationHRLCK8H-agg.ncml>
> ```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: please read: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public function click($url=null)
{
    var_dump($this->uri->segment('3'));
    $datauri['url']=$this->uri->segment('3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the url you have to pass the whole URL as a parameter. In controller, You can receive the url as parameter. Here you are not passing the url as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the URLs with `urlencode()` first like so:

```php
foreach ($dataView as $items){
    echo "<a href='".site_url("testcontroller/click/".urlencode($items['serviceURL'])."")."'>".$items>['serviceURL']."</a>".'<br>';    
}
```

I think the `/` after `http:` is interpreted as a different URL segment